# How can I compare a smarty variable to a javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, smarty

I have a function in javascript of which I have to compare smarty variable to a javascript variable : In the below case selected_variable is the javascript variable.

```
{if $Id == selected_variable}
{ foreach from=$actions item="action" key='actionId' name="actions" }
{ if $smarty.foreach.actions.last }
'{ $action|escape:'javascript':'UTF-8' }'                           
{ else }
'{ $action|escape:'javascript':'UTF-8' }',
{/if}   
{/foreach}
{/if}
```

Answer (score 2):

You said you have a javascript function. If its a JS function, it is as simple as

```
if(selected_variable == '{$yourSmartyVar}') {
 ...
}
```

But based on your code snippet it looks like you are trying to compare it using smarty. AFAIK, you cannot pass a client side variable into smarty the way you are showing since smarty is a server side.